# Implementation of SSL on SaaS App with separate domains

Tags: asp.net, ssl, saas, multiple-domains

We are developing a SaaS application in Asp.net, where we have used the Single application and Per Tenant Database. The application is more like a Saas e-commerce where SSL and data separation are required features. Now we want that every Tenant can have his separate top level domain names instead of the second level domains like 37Signals. So all the domains abc.com and xyz.com are using the same single app.

What I need to know is how to implement and deploy the https in the application so that everything works out fine, also how should we configure the NameServer and web application on IIS so that all the domains are pointing to the one application.

Comment: Better suited to ServerFault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently done this too (with IIS), and for me the process mainly consisted of this:

1. Create a * A DNS record (also known as a wildcard record)
2. Create an SSL certificate works for the * subdomain (At my registrar StartSSL I simply entered a * sign for the subdomain just as with the wildcard A DNS record).
3. To configure your app, parse the subdomain from HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["HOST"]

Comment: It seems not be an easy process, however i think the process you describes is for the Sub Domains, How about if each tenant have a separate top level domain like www.abc.com then what will be the process.

Comment: In that case you only have give your web app one dedicated IP address and point all these domains to that IP address. This might be ok for a handful of tenants, but you can't easily automate this when a new tenant signs up. Also, it's more expensive (sublevel domains are free). 

BTW: It's not really such a difficult process. it took me about 3 hours to figure out and set up everything.